# Lambert W called Product Log, More than 2 Branches

Tags: functions, logarithms, lambert-w, branch-cuts

This is really two questions.

1. Why is the Lambert W function alternatively called the **product log**? I have not found any reference to *why* it is called that, only that it occasionally is.
2. On the Wikipedia page for the Lambert W function, it states that the function has two branches, $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$. But on [a paper on the Wright Omega function](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/wrightomega.pdf), the authors state that there are infinite branches:

   > Lambert W satisfies $W(z)exp(W(z))=z$, and has an infinite number of branches, denoted $W_k(z)$, for $k\in \Bbb Z$.

   Which is correct?

Comment: $W$ has two *real* branches, but there are more complex-valued branches.

Comment: I think the name productLog comes from the fact that $\log(z)$ satisfies $e^{\log(z)} = z$ while $W(z)$ satisfies $W(z)e^{W(z)}= z$

Comment: it is a curious matter Wolfram Mathematica shuns all usage of the "Lambert Function" terminology in their (lengthy ) product log function documentation..   I wondered if there was some politics or some such there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lambert W is the inverse of

$$f(z) = ze^z$$

Since the inverse of $f(z) = e^z$ is called *logarithm*, it makes sense to call the inverse of the *product* $ze^z$ **product logarithm**.